# Netbeans IDE doesn't run (correct) php script for file uploading properly (local server)

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp

I've started to learn PHP. I've made a PHP script (php 5.6) for image uploading to the local server (XAMPP 5.6.24-1 on macOS Sierra).

```
<?php // upload.php
  echo <<<_END
    <html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
    <form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10'>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload'>
    </form>
_END;

  if ($_FILES)
  {
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
    echo "Uploaded image '$name'<br><img src='$name'>";
  }

  echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

**It works** if I address it through URL *in browser directly* (localhost/upload.php), so I guess it's not the permissions issue or something. But if I run the same file *in Netbeans IDE* (through "include path" option in new project preferences) the script shows [the form for uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIzLU.png) and fails [when I press "upload"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUsZf.png) (it doesn't depend on browser, I tried Safari, Firefox and Chrome with/without Netbeans connector plugin). The error as far as I get it is that the browser can not find the file in newly created temporary folder.

I would appreciate if someone point the very problem and solution!